# How do you call a 3d convex shape made of 8 arbitrary points?

Tags: geometry, terminology, 3d, solid-geometry

Is there a name for a 3d convex shape made of 8 arbitrary points ?
That would be like a cube or a box, except that the distances would not necessarily be equals, neither the angles necessarily be right angles.
In 2D, the equivalent would be a convex quadrilateral, but how do we translate this concept in 3D ?

Comment: I don't think there's a name, apart from polytope (the equivalent 2-D terms is polygon). There isn't anything too special about 4 random points in the plane, as opposed to 5, 6, 7, ...

Comment: A convex polytope with 8 vertices will generally have triangular faces, not quadrilateral faces, so it will be quite different from a box.  I don't think it has a name, although a 3-D polytope with 4 vertices is called a 3-simplex.

Comment: @CalvinLin and HewWolff Thank you for mentioning the "polytope" term, so it seems the closest to my "deformed box".

Comment: A polytope in 3D is called a *polyhedron*, just like a polytope in 2D is a polygon. If your polyhedron is so much like a box that it has six quadrilateral faces, it would be a *hexahedron*.

Comment: It sounds like you may also be interested in the "convex hull" of 8 points.